# Save View() output of RStudio as html

Tags: r, rstudio

Is it possible to save the page which I see when use `View()` command in RStudio on some data as an html file?

Comment: Have you noticed that when you right-click anywhere in RStudio, there is an "Inspect" option? It might be a little too cumbersome to do that every time, but I'd think that it's possible to copy-paste from out of the web inspector.

Comment: what do you mean as an html file? you want to save it as a table? https://github.com/gforge/htmlTable

Comment: If all you need is a package for table export to html, you might like the `xtable` package as well.

Comment: What version of RStudio are you using? In 0.98, you're literally looking at a .html file (you can use the aforementioned Inspect option to find the Iframe that points to it, and copy from there); in 0.99, the data viewer is a Web app that needs a connection to RStudio itself to stream new data, so there's no way to save it offline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe your data looks like the mtcars data

```
data(mtcars)
View(mtcars)

library(xtable)
```

sink command sends output to a file

```
sink('somehtmlfile.html')
print(xtable(mtcars),type='html')
```

then return things back to normal with

```
sink()
```

now open the somehtmlfile.html in a browser